# What footprint iOS or Android App leaves? and how to change it

Tags: appsec, android, ios, iphone, simcard

I've read some place that each phone and/or sim leaves some kind of footprints when it uses a social app (Google, Instagram etc.).

I would like to stay anonymous or at least blend in with the crowd.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly.
I would like to use the same phone / sim.
Each time I would like to connect using different profile, without any association to my old profile.
It's a given that ip needs to be changed each time I reconnect with a different profile.
But I was under the impression that, there is a unique identifier for each phone and sim.
Am I right?
What do I need to change to be able to manage my profiles and unique identifier?

Comment: Are you talking about Google, Instagram or etc?

Comment: Instagram, Facebook

Comment: Beware of things beyond IPs - https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/11/verizon-x-uidh

Answer (score 2):

Native apps (unlike websites in a browser) is able to directly access many unique IDs that identify your device/SIM. There's no way to change these unless you root/jailbreak and even so, apps may come up with [ingenious ways](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/11/ads_surreptitio.html) of fingerprinting still.

If you don't have to use the apps frequently, you can try the device emulators provided by Apple/Google.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use a major social network site, you leave your IP Address in your logs.

Basically when you sign up with your EMail Account, you create a link with your email and the social service, and then you put in your personal information and then that gets linked to your email.

If you buy and handset and load it with your contacts and use it, you create a web of information giving information about your personal life.

In short, your life is in a web of information and once your in it, it's hard to remove from it but it (if correct steps taken) disassociate from it.

So the answer is no, you cannot repair the already linked evidence

Answer (score -1):

Forget about using the App itself. Install a Tor Browser on your phone and connect through the TOR network. You can get new identities to switch between accounts and you will get a new IP address and such.

Comment: Can't forget the app. Must use it. Any other solutions?

Comment: You could possibly try looking into Privacy Blocker or rooting, installing a custom rom and using XPrivacy.